# Cycle2 State always false

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I have a Cycle2 slideshow.  I want it to cycle through slides every 5 seconds but I also want the user to be able to click the up or down key to advance a slide.  When the up or down key is clicked I want to make sure the slideshow is not busy before advancing to next or previous.  The problem is when I check .cycle-busy it returns false every time.  I set my slideshow to paused and tried checking .cycle-paused on click of the up or down key and THAT also returns false.  Am I missing something?

I'm using jquery 1.8.2.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    var busy = $('#mainSlideShow').is('.cycle-busy');
    alert(busy);
    if ($('.cycle-slideshow').is(':animated'))
        return false;

    switch (e.which) {
        case 38:
            $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('next');
            break;

        case 40:
            $('.cycle-slideshow').cycle('prev');
            break;
    }
});

<div id="mainSlideShow" >
    <div class="cycle-slideshow"
        data-cycle-timeout="5000"
        data-cycle-slides="> div"
        data-cycle-fx="scrollVert"
        data-cycle-prev=".prev"
        data-cycle-next=".next"
        data-cycle-paused="false">
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('Images/SlideShow/building.jpg');">
            <div class="slide-wrapper">
                <div class="next">
                    <img src="Images/prev.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="caption-wrapper">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h2 class="title">Commercial Products</h2>
                        <div class="description">
                            Specializing in small to mid-size businesses, RAM offers a wide variety of coverages to meet your business needs.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prev">
                    <img src="Images/next.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('Images/SlideShow/farm.jpg');">
            <div class="slide-wrapper">
                <div class="next">
                    <img src="Images/prev.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="caption-wrapper">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h2 class="title">Commercial Products</h2>
                        <div class="description">
                            Specializing in small to mid-size businesses, RAM offers a wide variety of coverages to meet your business needs.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prev">
                    <img src="Images/next.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('Images/SlideShow/family.jpg');">
            <div class="slide-wrapper">
                <div class="next">
                    <img src="Images/prev.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="caption-wrapper">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h2 class="title">Commercial Products</h2>
                        <div class="description">
                            Specializing in small to mid-size businesses, RAM offers a wide variety of coverages to meet your business needs.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prev">
                    <img src="Images/next.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="slide" style="background-image: url('Images/SlideShow/house.jpg');">
            <div class="slide-wrapper">
                <div class="next">
                    <img src="Images/prev.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="caption-wrapper">
                    <div class="caption">
                        <h2 class="title">Commercial Products</h2>
                        <div class="description">
                            Specializing in small to mid-size businesses, RAM offers a wide variety of coverages to meet your business needs.
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="prev">
                    <img src="Images/next.png" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of busy is contained in the option hash of the slideshow, to access this value, use the following method:

```
var opts = $('.cycle-slideshow' ).data( 'cycle.opts'); 
if(opts.busy){
    return false;
}
```